# Windows Universal Apps - Displaying SQLite data in Listview

Tags: c#, sqlite, win-universal-app

I've been trying to do this for a bit and don't have much code.. I'll show you my Meds.xaml and Meds.xaml.cs code, and see if I can get some help into binding the data into a Listview. Basically, a form is filled in, a button clicked, added to the database and updates the ListView.

**Meds.xaml**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Medication Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="43,255,0,0" Foreground="#FFC6C6C6" FontSize="18.667"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="medname_box" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="265,248,0,0" Width="186"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Medication Total Dose:" VerticalAlignment="Top"
```

.... and on and on

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="464" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="283" Margin="655,217,0,0" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged"/>
```

*Where I want the data displayed*

```
</Grid>
```

Now, here's Meds.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class Meds : Page
{
    string path;
    SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn;

    public Meds()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,
          "meds.sqlite");
        conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new
           SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
        conn.CreateTable<Medications>();

        var query = conn.Table<Medications>();
        string id = "";
        string MedName = "";
        string MedDose = "";
        int AM;
        int Noon;
        int Supper;
        int Night;
        int PRN;
        int Other;
        string WhatFor = "";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var z = conn.Insert(new Medications()
        {


            MedName = medname_box.Text,
            MedDose = meddose_box.Text,
```

Haven't figured out the checkboxes yet...

```
         // AM = ,
        // Noon = "",
        // Supper = "",
        // Night = "",
        // PRN = "",
        // Other = "",
        WhatFor = whatfor_box.Text
        });

        //          var query = conn.Table<Medications>();
        //               string id = "";
        //              string CurrentMood = "";


        //              foreach (var message in query)
        //             {
        //     id = id + " " + message.Id;
        //            CurrentMood = message.MedName;

        //         }
    }

        private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
 public class Medications
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
public string MedName { get; set; }
public string MedDose { get; set; }
public int AM { get; set; }
public int Noon { get; set; }
public int Supper { get; set; }
public int Night { get; set; }
public int PRN { get; set; }
public int Other { get; set; }
public string WhatFor { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: And your question is...? Please be a little more precise and remove unnecessary code like commented out stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and see if I can get some help into binding the data into a Listview. Basically, a form is filled in, a button clicked, added to the database and updates the ListView.

According to your description and based on the code you provided above, I have made a simple sample which shows how to display SQLite data in ListView using [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#binding-to-a-collection-of-items) and SQLite.Net-PCL for your reference:

**Meds.xaml**:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Header="Medication Name: " x:Name="medname_box" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" />
    <TextBox Header="Medication Total Dose: " x:Name="meddose_box" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" />
    <TextBox Header="What For: " x:Name="whatfor_box" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" />
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Click="btnAdd_Click" Width="186" Margin="0,5" />
    <Button x:Name="btnBack" Content="Back" Click="btnBack_Click" Width="186" Margin="0,5" />
    <ListView Header="Medications" x:Name="myList" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="400">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--Bind data to ListView Item, here I just bind three items for Medications, you can add other items if needed-->
                    <TextBlock x:Name="medName" Text="{Binding Path=MedName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="medDose" Text="{Binding Path=MedDose}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" x:Name="whatFor" Text="{Binding Path=WhatFor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

**Meds.xaml.cs**:

```
public sealed partial class Meds : Page
{
    private string DBPath { get; set; }

    public Meds()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Create the Database
        DBPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "meds.sqlite");
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<Medications>();
            // Set ItemsSource to the sqlite data for ListView
            myList.ItemsSource = conn.Table<Medications>();
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))
        {
            // Add Medications
            conn.Insert(new Medications
            {
                MedName = medname_box.Text,
                MedDose = meddose_box.Text,
                WhatFor = whatfor_box.Text
            });
            // Update the ItemsSource for ListView
            myList.ItemsSource = conn.Table<Medications>();
        }
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [Entire Sample](https://github.com/JerryWin/BindToListViewDemo) and following is the output:
[image]